# How to write a 2d-array C++ function-parameter (eg. for int[x][y])?

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I have an 2D-Array

```
int tilemap[800][600];
```

I want to use such an Araay in an Function (as parameter)

```
void load(int* tiles);
```

But the datatype `int*` is not the right one.

What is the right one? I have no idea.

Thanks!

Comment: `void load(int tiles[800][600]);` ?

Comment: `void load(int **tiles)` is perhaps the one you are looking for. But vectors would be better

Comment: Dont work! `no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘int (*)[40][30]’ to ‘int**’`

Comment: That is a function pointer

Comment: Sorry what? What for an type must i set in my arguments?

Comment: @EdHeal `int **tiles` for a 2d array?? You must be joking.

Comment: @EdHeal No, it is completely wrong. Array of pointers is not compatible in any way to an array of arrays.

Comment: Revenge downvoting... really.

Comment: @EdHeal: A function pointer?  What?  No, it certainly is not a function pointer.  Function pointer looks like that: `returntype (*pointername)(args)`

Comment: @2501 - Was looking up a previous answer about subscript and had an accident - hopefully I have rectified it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void load(int tiles[][600]);
```

You can have matrix in two ways. One is using pointer to array of pointers (rows) to array of data.

Other way is the way you have chosen.
It's, as you sad, a 2-D array, which means that (in case of c/c++) rows of data are one behind of other in memory.
This matrix:

```
 +-------+
 | 7 | 9 |
 +-------+
 | 5 | 2 |
 +-------+
```

is represented like this in memory:

```
[ [7] [9] ] [ [5] [2] ]
```

To get element at position [1][0], computer needs to calculate it's address from address of matrix (the address of it's first element) and position numbers.
In the above example you see that address of [1][0] is (address of number 7) + 2*sizeof(int), that is &matrix + 2.
So the actual formula to calculate address of element [i][j] is

```
&matrix + (number_of_columns*i + j)
```

I omitted *sizeof(int) or *sizeof(type) because arithmetic that includes pointer and integer already includes that, but if &matrix is raw address to some data, without knowledge of it's type it should be included.
That's what happens at level of machine instructions, computer calculates

```
 address_of_matrix + (number_of_columns*i + j)*sizeof(type)
```

So you need to tell compiler at least what is number of columns this matrix has.
You'll also need number of rows of course, but that's something you need, not compiler.

I hope it's clearer. It's hard to explain it here. But there are a lot of material on the net.

Answer (score 1):

> the datatype `int*` is not the right one.

Actually, it is just fine.  An array of arrays has all elements stored sequentially, so a pointer to the first is sufficient to find all the others.

The "best" option, though, is a reference-to-array-of-array, because that will preserve the size information:

```
template<size_t M, size_t N>
void load(int (&tiles)[M][N])
{
}
```

(Note that like all templates, the definition should be visible at the point of instantiation)

If the second extent is always fixed, you can pass an array-of-array as pointer-to-array, because array-of-`T` can always be passed as pointer-to-`T`:

```
void load(int (*tiles)[600])
{
}
```

This is what both Marko and 2501's example code is doing, although they are using a misleading syntax that looks like an array, while in fact it is a pointer.

Comment: I was just trying to say that compiler needs to know how many columns there are, and why. OK, it's not the best way to declare it but works the same thing.

Comment: @Marko: Your code is correct, although looks like an array when it isn't.  I didn't downvote.

Comment: And I agree. It should also be told that void f(int array[]); is not really accepting array. That is, it's not copying array to pass it to function, but actually just passes pointer, just like void f(int* array);